# Get the name from panel on clicking the apply button and INSERT into another table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have a job and apply-now in same panel and fetching the job details from database. How can I get the name of job when clicked on apply-now button.
[image]

**jobs.php**

```
    <div class="container clearfix">
                    <div class="col_three_fifth nobottommargin">
                    <?php
                        include('admin/config.php');
                            $host    = "localhost";
                            $user    = "root";
                            $pass    = "";
                            $db_name = "demo";
                            $lastId="";
                            $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);
                            $sql = "SELECT * FROM job_update";
                            $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
                            {
                             while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))

                            {
                        ?>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" >
                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#<?php echo $row['id']?>" aria-expanded="true"  class="trigger collapsed">
                         <?php echo $row['job_name'];?>
                        </a>
                      </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="<?php echo $row['id']?>" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" >
                      <div class="panel-body">
                        <ul class="iconlist iconlist-color nobottommargin" style="list-style-type: disc!important;">
                            <?php
                             // echo '<li>'.nl2br($row['job_description']).'</li>'
                            echo '<li>'.str_replace(array("\r","\n\n","\n"),array('',"\n","</li>\n<li>"),trim($row['job_description'],"\n\r")).'</li>';
                            ?>
                       </ul>
                        <a href="#apply"><button id="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class="btn btn-primary apply pull-right">Apply Now</button></a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <?php 
                }
            }
            ?>      
            </div>
 </div>
```

How can I get the id or name from the panel when clicked on apply-now button.

Thank you in Advance!!!

Comment: fyi, you have at least two elements with an `id="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"`. `id`s should be unique in your document. Also, unless `$row['id']` is a string, your `id`s value is wrong, needs to start with a char

Comment: You could use `data`-attributes

Answer (score 1):

Add these two tags inside your `html` just above the button which one you clicked.

```
<input type="hidden" id="job_id" value="<?php echo $row['id']?>">
<input type="hidden" id="job_name" value="<?php echo $row['job_name'];?>">
```

Then after you have to call `click` function in j query when you click the button.

```
$("button").click(function(){
    alert($("#job_id").val())  //job_id would be your tag id where you put job id
    alert($("#job_name").val()) //job_name would be your tag id where you put job name.
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.How to insert the job_name in another table

Comment: use ajax to request `PHP URL` and get `job_name` on php page then you can insert into any table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want name of job. So, you have to use on click function jquery.

```
<input type="hidden" class="job" name="job_name" value="<?php echo $row['job_name'];?>">
<button id="submit">apply now</button>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(){
            job_name = $(".job").val();
            alert(job_name);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Now let's hope there's only one `$(".job").val();`